# Simplifying nested fractions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

No juicy title this time :(

$$1+\dfrac1{1+{\dfrac1{1+\dfrac1{1+\dfrac1x}}}}$$

Is there a special trick for solving this type of problem?

Comment: You are encouraged to learn. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Click `edit` on your [previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1954425/simplifying-frac-fracx1-x-frac1xx-frac1-xx-fracx1x) and see how the edit was done to format it properly. Then you can cancel out of edit mode, so that no changes are actually saved.

Comment: WOW I GOT IT!!!!

Comment: can someone answer now

Comment: @juicywatermelons I just did!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We simplify step-by-step:

$$1+\dfrac1{1+{\dfrac1{1+\dfrac1{\frac{x+1}{x}}}}}$$

$$1+\dfrac1{1+{\dfrac1{1+\frac{x}{x+1}}}}$$

$$1+\dfrac1{1+{\dfrac1{\frac{2x+1}{x+1}}}}$$

$$1+\dfrac1{1+\frac{x+1}{2x+1}}$$

$$1+\dfrac1{\frac{3x+2}{2x+1}}$$

$$1+\frac{2x+1}{3x+2}$$

$$\frac{5x+3}{3x+2}$$

Comment: Surprise attack by the Fibonacci numbers...

Comment: @MarioCarneiro I wonder what happens when we continue this process indefinitely :)

Comment: $$\frac{p_n}{q_n}=1+\frac{1}{\frac{p_{n-1}}{q_{n-1}}}=\frac{p_{n-1}+q_{n-1}}{p_{n-1}}$$